# Frequent crashes deallocating CCNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, dealloc

I have an object in my game that inherits from `CCLayer`. This layer, `MainLayer`, is the main component of the game where most of the actions happen and sprites are displayed.

The problem that I'm having and have been trying for hours to fix, is deallocating this `MainLayer`. This layer has many children and many actions. The most annoying part is that only sometimes does it crash when it's deallocated, other times it works fine, and I can't see any difference in the situations.

The part that it crashes at is the `dealloc` method for `CCNode`:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    CCLOGINFO( @"cocos2d: deallocing %@", self);

    [actionManager_ release];
    [scheduler_ release];
    [camera_ release];
    [grid_ release];
    [shaderProgram_ release];
    [userObject_ release];

    // children
    CCNode *child;
    CCARRAY_FOREACH(children_, child)
        child.parent = nil;

    [children_ release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Specifically failing at `child.parent = nil;` with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Comment: This sounds like memory corruption or accessing a deallocated object. Try using `Product -> Analyze` on Xcode and see if that reports any possible problems. Also check for retain cycles.

Comment: you are most certainly releasing one of its children somewhere in the game logic. Stick with constructors that return autorelease'd objects with cocos2d, and avoid retaining/releasing them as much as possible. Let the children array do all the retaining for you. Good luck finding which object is the culprit.

Comment: So since this problem is happening in the children array, the object causing the problem must be/inherit from a CCNode, and must have been added a child to my layer... So I must be calling release on one of these objects somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You're releasing objects that the super class takes care of. As far as I can tell the entire dealloc method here is superfluous. It will over-release all the internal objects.

PS: use ARC if you aren't close to releasing the app.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, he doesn't have any `dealloc` method. He pasted the code from `CCNode`'s `dealloc` method.

Comment: Is there a way to release an object without explicitly calling release?

Comment: I seem to have fixed my issue somehow. I made all of my objects that inherit from CCNode autorelease. Changed a bunch of other things and it's not crashing on me anymore.

Comment: Oh, ok that makes sense. I thought that was the reimplementation of the method. My bad.